# How to display product descriptions automatically in mobile version?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, rwd, mobile

We are using 1.9.0.1, the rwd theme.

By default, you need to click "Description" when viewing a product on your phone, and then the description will drop down and show.

I feel like a lot of customers glance over this, and I would like the description to load automatically.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your `styles.css` and apply the following style

```
@media (max-width: 770px)
{
  .product-collateral > dl > dd {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**edit:** Should point out this was written with v1.9.1.0 in mind. There were various modifications to the RWD theme since 1.9.0.1 so the solution may need adapting.

The accepted solution will end up opening *all* the tabs in the mobile view. OP mentioned only the description.

To make the first tab start open the answer lies within in `skin/frontend/rwd/default/app.js` which handles, amongst various other things, the behaviour of the tabs in the product view.

Investigate the block of code starting at line 872, "UI Pattern - Toggle Content (tabs and accordions in one setup)", specifically lines 938-941:

```
//Open the first accordion if desired.
if (startOpen) {
    dts.eq(0).trigger('click');
}
```

`startopen` determines whether the first tab is triggered. Where is `startopen` defined? Line 881:

```
var startOpen = wrapper.hasClass('open');
```

The wrapper in this case is the .toggle-content div. It does not, by default, have the class `open` - you'll have to add that yourself in your copy of `<template-dir>/catalog/product/view.phtml` line 175:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
```

to...

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs open">
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: It worked for me. This answer is the accepted solution. Thank you @Turpachull

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in magento 1.9.2.1 and i fixed it by just adding a css class to main div of the accordion.

If you open the file `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and at bottom of the file you will find html like below:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
```

Just change add `accordion-open` css class. So the hmlt will be like

```
 <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs accordion-open">
```

In my version of magento, it adds the `current` css class to first accordion tab, so the above changes will make the first tab to be open automatically.

Hope it will help.